# Find lowest leaf nodes in a binary tree

Tags: c#

So this is probably a popular problem, and I decided to take a crack at it today using C#.

I came up with the following solution:

```
private  BinaryTree<int>.BinaryTreeNode FindLowestNodes(BinaryTree<int>.BinaryTreeNode node, int depth, ref int biggestDepth) {
    this.WriteResult("Entering recursiorn for node.....{0}", node.Value.ToString());
    BinaryTree<int>.BinaryTreeNode lowestNode = null;
    if (node.Left != null) { 
        var n = FindLowestNodes(node.  Left, depth + 1, ref biggestDepth);
        if (n != null) lowestNode = n;
    }
    if (node.Right != null) { 
        var n = FindLowestNodes(node.Right, depth + 1, ref biggestDepth);
        if (n != null)
            lowestNode = n;
    }
    if (node.Left == null && node.Right == null) {
        if (depth > biggestDepth) { 
            lowestNode = node;
            biggestDepth = depth;
        }
    }
    return lowestNode;
}
```

This is a recursive function using a `depth` parameter, and `biggestDepth` parameter that helps me determine if the node is indeed the lowest since the tree can have multiple depths. What I don't like about passing an int by reference is boxing...

Could this solution be written more efficiently?

Also, would it be easier to parallelize using a functional language like Clojure, or is that not really a factor as long as variables are not passed by reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an int with the `ref` keyword does *not* involve any boxing at all. Do not confuse this with "passing an int by reference" (as in, a function with return type `Object` returning an `int`,) which is quite a different thing, and it *does* involve boxing.

Your code seems quite efficient to me, I have nothing to comment on.

Comment: looking at your thumbnail i thought i just got advice from Peter Gibbons from office space :)

Comment: !LOL! yeah, now that you mention it, it is true, my icon kinda looks like him!  I know the actor, I did not know his name, (I just looked him up,) and I always thought he might be Greek. With a name like Gibbons he cannot be Greek, of course.

Comment: well his actual name is Ron Livingston. also not very Greek sounding